# Need shell script to read line with matching content

Tags: shell-script

I have an abc.txt file it is having 100 lines. I wanted to read the specific content from that 100 lines and print that matching line. Below is the text file.

```
2018-09-12 11:00:02.290 [main] INFO  ProxyCollector  : proxyDomainInfo com.nielsen.emm.parser.ProxyDomainServerInfo@105e55ab
2018-09-12 11:00:02.296 [main] INFO  ProxyCollector  : country code---de
2018-09-12 11:00:02.296 [main] INFO  ProxyCollector  : sftp archiveDir---/incoming/log_archive/DE/archive/
2018-09-12 11:06:32.802 [main] DEBUG ProxyFileProcessor  : Directory /marklogic/ProxyCollection/dirs/error/de/ Created
2018-09-12 11:06:32.802 [main] INFO  ProxyCollector  : Raw Files Count ::  4  File Count in incoming dir :: 4 For a Country :: de
2018-09-12 11:06:32.802 [main] INFO  ProxyCollector  : IpAddress in the FileName: 193.34.145.31
2018-09-12 11:06:32.803 [main] INFO  ProxyCollector  : IpAddress in the FileName: 85.10.197.226
```

we want to read the line from `country code---de`
end's with
`Raw Files Count ::  4  File Count in incoming dir :: 4 For a Country :: de`

Comment: The `sed` command would be appropriate for this.

Answer (score 1):

In the [`sed` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

- read [chapter 4](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses)
- read about the [`p` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands)
- read about the `-n` [command line option](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options)